# Python Selenium - text_to_be_present_in_element with numbers

Tags: python, selenium, element

I'm trying to wait for an element to match a specific number with Selenium in Python. It basically can assume every value between 0 and 100. Matching words is functional but matching numbers is a bit problematic.

The code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, 'price'),"1"))
```

matches the value 1 but also 10,11,21 and every number that contains "1".
Is there a more pythonic and efficient way than this?

```
while price != '1':
    price = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'price'))).text
```

Thanks. Df.

Comment: `WHILE PRICE != '1':` is not pythonic

Comment: How about that `print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="price" and text()="1"]'))).text)`

Comment: @KunduK That made it. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your text to an integer value like this:

```
PRICE = int(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'price'))).text)
```

Now you can check with a number instead of strings